# branch rule requiring checks before merging does not see checks

Tags: github, branch, rules, probot

I'm setting up a branch rule in my repositories and want the branch rule to require five checks before merging

This is what I want to see:
[ability to add five checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSf6R.png)

Here's what I see:
[ability to add only 2 checks out of 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brL2k.png)

I have the same mergeble.yml files in two repositories
but in 1 case I can set up a branch rule for all five checks
and in case 2 only for two checks

All other settings in the repositories are the same
I don't understand why in the second repository I can't add the other three checks